# How to select CMU Sans Serif Bold in XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex

I have the bold font installed:

```
fc-list | grep CMU | grep Sans | grep Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/cmu/cmunso.ttf: CMU Sans Serif:style=BoldOblique
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/cmu/cmunsx.ttf: CMU Sans Serif:style=Bold
```

But I do not know how to select it.

This throws an error:

```
\font\tenbf="CMU Sans Serif Bold" at 14pt
```

> Font \tenbf="CMU Sans Serif Bold" at 14.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.

And this does not throw an error, but the result is not bold:

```
\font\tenbf="CMU Sans Serif:style=Bold" at 14pt
```

How to select the bold font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You add the `/B` selector.

```
\font\tenbf="CMU Sans Serif/B"
\tenbf ABC
\bye
```

The font selector can be `I`, `B` or `BI`.

You find the documentation with [`texdoc xetex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xetex/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf), section 1.

Comment: @ceving Added the info