# How to find out why the font search fails?

Tags: fonts, xetex, plain-tex

I migrated my XeTeX PDF generation from a Debian 9 system to the CentOS 7. The Red Hat packages of XeTeX where totally outdated and I had to remove them all, in order to install the latest TeX Live version.

After the installation I have added the TeX Live fonts to the operating system configuration:

```
# cp $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
# fc-cache -fsv
```

And the CMU Sans Serif Bold font is known by fontconfig:

```
$ fc-list |grep CMU | grep Sans | grep Bold | grep -v Extended
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunso.otf: CMU Sans Serif:style=BoldOblique
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunsx.otf: CMU Sans Serif:style=Bold
```

On my Debian system I used the bold font in this way:

```
\font\tenbf="CMU Sans Serif/B" at 14pt
```

This has been recommended in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484896/175011).

But this does not work any more on the new system. And I do not get any error. The definition gets silently ignored. And instead of the bold font I get the normal font.

But when I specify the correct name of the font file, it get the correct bold font:

```
\font\tenbf="[cmunsx]" at 14pt
```

How can I find out, why the font selection does not work, if I use the name of the font instead of the name of the file?

**Update**

I tried to follow Ulrike's comment, but I still do not see the error.

This is my test file `bf.tex`:

```
\XeTeXtracingfonts=1
\font\tenrm="CMU Sans Serif"
\tenrm RM
\font\tenbf="CMU Sans Serif/B"
\tenbf BF
\bye
```

This is the output of `xetex`:

```
$ xetex --no-pdf bf.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xetex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./bf.tex [1] )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on bf.xdv (1 page, 452 bytes).
Transcript written on bf.log.
```

This is the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xetex 2019.7.4)  5 JUL 2019 09:39
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**bf.tex
(./bf.tex
Requested font "CMU Sans Serif" scaled 1000
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.
otf
Requested font "CMU Sans Serif/B" scaled 1000
 -> /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.
otf
 [1] )
Output written on bf.xdv (1 page, 452 bytes).
```

This is the output of `xdvipdfmx`:

```
$ xdvipdfmx -vv bf.xdv
<FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>bf.xdv -> bf.pdf
DVI Comment:  XeTeX output 2019.07.05:0939
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf@9.96pt<NATIVE-FONTMAP:/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf".
(CID:CMUSansSerif)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf/0/H/65536/0/0,0>.
>]
otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf"...
(CID:/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunss.otf[VSJZVN+CMUSansSerif][CIDFontType0][6 glyphs][753 bytes])
Compression saved 465 bytes
2360 bytes written
```

I can see that in both cases the same font file is used. But I still do not understand why.

Comment: Add \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 and compile with `xetex --no-pdf file ` and then `xdvipdfmx -vv file` to get more info.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by specifying the file name of the font.

```
\font\bf="[cmunsx]" at 14pt
\font\rm="[cmunss]" at 11pt
\font\tt="[cmuntt]" at 11pt
```